# Get cursor position in coordinates at Leaflet map in angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate of another but I can't find any solution for my problem.

I have an app based on Angular 6 and Leaflet map (not ngx-leflet). I need to get position of my cursor in coordinates on map at every mouse movement. I think I could use [this](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.4.0.html#mouseevent) handling events for Leaflet, but I don't know how to combine it with my map. Here is example of usage it with a custom widget:

widget-options.model.ts

```
import { Map, ControlOptions } from 'leaflet';

export interface WidgetsOptions extends ControlOptions {
    map: Map;
}
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
    // ... init zoom and width 
    mapWidgetsOptions$: Observable<WidgetsOptions>;

    mapReady(map: Map) {
        this.mapWidgetsOptions$ = of<WidgetsOptions>({
            position: 'bottomleft',
            map: map
            // should I add here mousePosition ?
        });
    }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<app-map (mapReady)="mapReady($event)">

    <map-widgets [options$]="mapWidgetsOptions$"></map-widgets>

</app-map>
```

map-widget.component.ts

```
 export class MapWidgetsComponent extends Control implements OnInit {

    @Input() options$: Observable<WidgetsOptions>;

    constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
        super();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.options$
            .pipe(
                take(1)
            )
            .subscribe(options => {
                this.options = options;
                this.addTo(options.map);
            });
    }

    onAdd(map: Map): HTMLElement {
        return this.element.nativeElement;
    }
}
```

Could anybody provide an example of how to make it?

Comment: Start by providing a sandbox to play with. Your post should include a [mcve] and what you have already tried to resolve your issue.

Comment: See `Leaflet.MousePosition` plugin (https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#mouse-coordinates)

Comment: it depends on how you are integrating leaflet. In theory yes on a click event get the map object, hook to the event and get the coordinates. Its a vague question. this is how I do it. https://github.com/elasticrash/Angular.io.MapViewer/blob/master/src/app/display-coordinates/coordinates.ts. But I've created my own library package. so this example may not be the best

Comment: @xmojmr I've added code

Answer (score 3):

You need to extend Leaflet control while listening to mousemove event:

```
const Coordinates = L.Control.extend({
    onAdd: map => {
      const container = L.DomUtil.create("div");
      map.addEventListener("mousemove", e => {
          container.innerHTML = `
          <h2>Latitude is 
            ${e.latlng.lat.toFixed(4)} <br> 
            and Longitude is  ${e.latlng.lng.toFixed(4)}
            </h2>
          `;
     });
     return container;
   }
});
map.addControl(new Coordinates({ position: "bottomleft" }));
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/m7o9195wp)

Note that Angular 7 is used instead of 6

**Update**:

A second way would be to use external library Leaflet.MousePosition & integrate it with Angular

Just install the library, import it, add its relevant css & use this line of code inside `ngOnInit` to instantiate mousePosition.

```
...
import * as L from "leaflet";
import "leaflet-mouse-position";

ngOnInit() {
    const map = L.map("map").setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    ...
    L.control.mousePosition().addTo(map);
}
```

and on styles.css add

```
.leaflet-container .leaflet-control-mouseposition {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #bbb;
  padding: 0 5px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #333;
  font: 11px/1.5 "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

[Alternative method demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/nwxj81koo0)

Comment: yes, I see it works. but how can I apply acoording my logic? I'm guessing I have much esier way to add it inside my `MapWidgetsComponent ` just getting lat and lng from mouseMove event and make an interpolation inside  `MapWidgetsComponent ` template. I asked how can I add this https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#mouse-coordinates to my existing widget

Comment: Your question before you edited it was can someone provide an example of how to do it. My answer was pointing right there. Moreover, since something is so easy to achieve without a library why to add another dependency to your project?  Last but not least I provide a second way to do the exact same thing using Leaflet.MousePosition. Check the updated answer.